# Make an authenticated SIP call via URI

Tags: authentication, asterisk, voip, url, sip

I'm trying to redirect a phone number to a SIP address that's only accessible when authenticated.

Given the following, how would the SIP URI look like (if possible) ?
SIP Server: `sip.example.com`
Auth user: `myuser`
Auth password: `mypass`
User to call: `targetuser`

Calling `targetuser@sip.example.com` doens't go throught if not authenticated.
I only have the option to specify a SIP URI.

Answer (score 2):

The format for SIP URIs in general is

```
sip:user:password@host:port;uri-parameters?headers
```

So in this case you'd need

```
sip:myuser:mypass@sip.example.com?to=sip:targetuser%40sip.example.com
```

Notice the difference between:

- `sip.example.com:port` calls `gethostbyname()` to resolve DNS
- `sip.example.com` without port number uses `SRV` records instead.

You must also be aware that [RFC3261](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) discourages using the `password` SIP URI component:

> `password`:
>      A password associated with the user.  While the SIP and
>      SIPS URI syntax allows this field to be present, its use is NOT
>      RECOMMENDED, because the passing of authentication information
>      in clear text (such as URIs) has proven to be a security risk
>      in almost every case where it has been used.  For instance,
>      transporting a PIN number in this field exposes the PIN.